# Python sqlite3 decoding str in not supported

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently trying to interface with my SQL database using python, I get this very strange error when I run my code, the error is :

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/media/james/James's HDD/QE Things/Computing CourseWork/New and improved USE THESE ONES/testdb.py", line 16, in      sql=str("INSERT INTO Server_Log (LogID, Log) VALUES",(server_log3)) TypeError: decoding str is not supported".

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3 as db

con = None
server_log=[["message_redirect","Dan"],["message_redirect","James"]]
for i in range(0,len(server_log)):
    server_log1=server_log[i][0]
    server_log2=server_log[i][1]
    print(server_log1)
    print(server_log2)
    server_log3=server_log1+"," +server_log2
    print(server_log3)
    sql=str("INSERT INTO Server_Log (LogID, Log) VALUES",  (server_log3))
try:
    con = db.connect('data.db',isolation_level=None)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchone()
    #for data in data:
    print(data)
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
    print("done")
```